# RewriteRule working on .htaccess but not httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm trying to redirect all urls that have `/__/` to `/public/assets/` and got it working in .htaccess but not globally in httpd.conf
What it should do is re-write:

`http://example.com/__/test.css`

to

`http://example.com/public/assets/test.css`

So far I have this working for .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?__/(.*)$ $1/public/assets/$2 [L]
```

(Which might not be written properly but it's the only way I managed to make it work). If I put it in httpd.conf however, it doesn't work at all. I tried tweaking it, tried putting it inside `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>` and inside `<Directory "c:/DEV/wamp/www/">` but it still won't work. Been losing 3 hours of time on this now and found plenty of examples on Stackoverflow/forums, but oddly none of them work for me..

**EDIT:**
Here are two examples of blocks I tried. [R] is to verify if the rule was working and redirecting:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "c:/DEV/wamp/www/"
    <Directory "c:/DEV/wamp/www/">
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)?__/(.*)$ /$1public/assets/$2 [R]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this one:

```
<Directory "c:/DEV/wamp/www/">
    Allow From All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)?__/(.*)$ /$1public/assets/$2 [R]
</Directory>
```

**EDIT2:**
Tried selected edit from proposed answer, still cannot find the css files on the server.

```
<Directory "c:/DEV/wamp/www/">
    Allow From All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^__/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: And you say "doesn't work" - it literally does nothing? Is your .htaccess file located at `c:/DEV/wamp/www/.htaccess`? If so, then the corresponding `<Directory>` section _should_ work. Maybe add your VirtualHost block to your question.

Comment: yes sorry.. doesn't work = rule is ignored completely. And yep, .htaccess is    there: "c:/DEV/wamp/www/.htaccess". I will add the blocks I tried to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `RewriteRule ^/(.*)?__/(.*)$`

You've included a slash prefix on your `RewriteRule` pattern in the `<Directory>` container. This should be the same as in your .htaccess file, ie. no directory-prefix.

.htaccess files and `<Directory>` containers behave the same in this respect. Only when the directive is *directly* in the server config / VirtualHost container should the directory-prefix be included (but then it matches the URL-path, not the filesystem path, as it does in a .htaccess / Directory context).

If you put it in a `<Directory>` container then there should be no need to "tweak it".

> I'm trying to redirect

Strictly speaking, this is an *internal rewrite* (as you have in your .htaccess file), rather than an *external redirect*.

---

> `/__/<file>` to `/public/assets/<file>`
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?__/(.*)$ $1/public/assets/$2 [L]`

This rewrite can be simplified, providing `/__/` always occurs at the start of the URL-path. Try the following in either a .htaccess file or `<Directory>` container:

```
RewriteRule ^__/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
```

---

### [EDIT] WARNING: mod_rewrite inheritance

If you are switching between testing .htaccess and `<Directory>` containers in your server config and wondering why the directives in the `<Directory>` container aren't doing anything then it's possible that the mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess are completely overriding the directives in the `<Directory>` container. This is the default behaviour. .htaccess directives will take priority and parent directives are not inherited by default.

Generally, if you are using `<Directory>` containers in the server config then you don't need .htaccess, so the easiest option is to simply disable them in your `<Directory>` container with `AllowOverride None`. So, the `<Directory>` container looks like:

```
<Directory "c:/DEV/wamp/www/">
Allow From All
AllowOverride None
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^__/(.*)$ public/assets/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

If you needed to have mod_rewrite directives in both .htaccess and a parent `<Directory>` container then you would need to explicitly enable mod_rewrite inheritance by placing the following directive in .htaccess:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

If you are on Apache 2.4 then you have more options.

You can't simply disable the rewrite engine in .htaccess (ie. `RewriteEngine Off`) since that will also prevent the parent directives from being processed. If you simply remove the `RewriteEngine` directive from .htaccess then the `RewriteEngine On` directive in the `<Directory>` container will enable the rewrite engine but will result in the .htaccess directives overriding the parent again, so you are back to requiring the `RewriteOptions Inherit` directive.

Comment: Thanks :) But I tried already without the slash prefix and it wasn't working either. I read somewhere that Rewrites in httpd.conf needed the extra slash so I tried it and ended up copy-pasting that version of the code here. Basically all I want is http://domain.com/__/test.css BECOMES http://domain.com/public/assets/test.css but RewriteRule /__/ /public/assets/ did not work in .htaccess, neither did RewriteRule (.*)/__/(.*) $1/public/assets/$2. That's why I have an ugly rule that I suspect is the problem.

Comment: Does `/__/` always occur at the start of the URL path? Presumably there are multiple files, not just `test.css`?

Comment: Yes, it always occurs at the beginning of the url, right after the domain.. I don't know why the original developers put "/__/" in the url. And yep, there are several css/js files in that asset folder :)

Comment: In that case the directive can be simplified. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question again. Your new directive works perfect in .htaccess but not in httpd.conf again. I pasted the exact code I used. I also tried wrapping the <Directory> in <VirtualHost >. I was starting to think that httpd.conf was not read, but my other <VirtualHost> directives work perfectly.

Comment: Just to confirm, you will need to restart Apache after every change to the server config (ie. VirtualHost and Directory containers).

Comment: Ah, just wondered... if you've been switching between .htaccess and `<Directory>` containers whilst testing then it's quite possible that your .htaccess mod_rewrite directives are completely overriding your parent `<Directory>` directives. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply time, that was unprofessional from me! I just tested that out and it works now! Thanks!